# WordPress where find code function the_excerpt()?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code:

```
            <div class="entry-summary">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
```

But I would like to edit what the_excerpt function displays. Is it possible to reach the_excerpt function code? Where to find that function in WordPress files?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a proper IDE, then you will be able to search across the whole code base, or even to just click on the function in the above code ...

Comment: Or just go look it up in the documentation ... https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/#source

Comment: Just a warning, that is one of the harder functions to tweak if you are outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the output of `the_excerpt()` by hooking to it in `functions.php`:

Add the following code to your `functions.php`:

```
function my_custom_excerpt($excerpt) {
    $excerpt = 'some prefix text ' . $excerpt . ' ...and some more';
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_custom_excerpt', 999 );
```

WordPress is open source, so you can view the source code for any function (including `the_excerpt()`) on the WP Developer Resources website: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Also, here is a guide for changing different parts of the excerpt:
https://wpshout.com/wordpress-post-excerpts/

**UPDATE:**

Add the following code to your `functions.php`:

```
function my_clean_excerpt($excerpt) {
    $excerpt = str_replace('UDOSTĘPNIJ:', "", $excerpt);
    return $excerpt;
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_clean_excerpt', 999 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "reach the_excerpt function code". If you want to change the output of the_excerpt() you can use the_excerpt filter. If you want to change the code of the_excerpt() you can find it in wp-includes/post-template.php.